# MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT is not working well

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm using Google pixel(8.0.1) with below code to capture video from camera.

```
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, VIDEO_FILE_SIZE) 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, VIDEO_DURATION)
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
```

i'have given video size is 100 MB. and Video duration is 60 seconds.

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 100) 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60)
```

so in pixel(8.0.1) it will be stop on approx 00:40 seconds.and in LG
   nexus(6.0.1) it will not stop on 60 second even recording will be
   continue after 60 second. Is there an another way to limit the
   capture video duration on 6.0 + devices?